# Problems with getting values from JSON object

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get data once user logged in successfully but I never get any of results, what I am doing is next:

```
// response is my request to server
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
Log.d("RESPONSE",obj.toString());
```

so in log I do see values, like:

```
04-19 11:28:16.729: D/RESPONSE(3162): {"data":[{"loses":3,"username":"benedict","level":1,"strength":15,"experience":null,"gold":10,"password":"benedict","intelligence":5,"agility":10,"wins":5}],"status":true}
```

but once I try to read username for example like this:

```
String username = obj.getString("username");
```

The code above ^ gives me nothing in my string.. 
Any help how I can retrieve data from JSONObject? Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn [JSON Parsing](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/).

Comment: Yep, I indeed need to, first time trying and dont really have alot of time to go throught tutorial so I was trying here. If you know any good tutorial please suggest, I can google random too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the `username` is present in the `data` object, which happens to be an `JSONArray`. Get the `data` array from the **response** object, traverse through each `JSONObject` in the array, and from each object, extract your `username`.

Something like this:-

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
    JSONObject eachData = data.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("Username= "+ eachData.getString("username"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it right now, first time working with json :)

Comment: million thanks, its working fine! need to wait 2 mins then accept answer

Answer (score 2):

your field username is in array data. To access into this try :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("data");

for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i){
    JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String username = data.getString("username");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first get `JSONArray` which is `data` :

```
    JSONArray data = null;
        data = json.getJSONArray("data");
         for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
         String username = c.getString("username");
}
```

You can get idea about parsing JSON from [HERE](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

try {

```
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {

           JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
           String loose= Jasonobject.getString("loses");
           String username=Jasonobject.getString("username");
          ....... 
          ........



        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("log_txt", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```